# Positioning a repeat element - CSS

Tags: css

I am trying to get to grips with the positioning of a few elements on my website, and all I am after is a few pointers as to how you guys would go about it.

Essentially, this is the concept that I want to create. We are focussing on the coloured journey boxes ("The Red Kite", "QuayLink", "Toon Link", etc.). What would you do to create something like this?

[image: like this]

This section should fill the width of the screen. But the current code that I have does not:

[image: Current]

Truth be told, I have no idea how to approach this. I have tried having each box with the class 'journey-box', defined as:

```
.journey-box{

display: block;
float: left;
margin: 1%;
padding: 0.9em;
text-align: center;
min-width: 16em;

}
```

All wrapped in a container:

```
section{

margin: 0 auto;
text-align: center;
width: 100%;

}
```

But to no avail. Any help would be appreciated.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/oinkk/d4Agv/

Cheers

Comment: Can you please say it cleary..? I think the min-width causing problem..moreover am not understand your question.

Comment: A simple http://jsfiddle.net reproducing this problem will also be helpful

Comment: Does your page have a fixed width or you are aiming for a flexible design using % length values, and if so, how many blocks per row do you want?

Comment: My CSS is probably a mess: http://jsfiddle.net/oinkk/d4Agv/

Comment: I am aiming for a flexible design, with varying amounts of blocks per row depending on the width of the screen. But at all times the blocks must be evenly distributed across the screen.

Comment: How wide do you want the blocks to be?

Comment: They must be wide enough to fit the text on at the current size. 250px seems to be the sweet spot.

Comment: If the number of blocks per row can vary depending on the screen width, then it will be difficult to distribute them evenly without using JavaScript to adjust the left/right margins on the blocks.

Answer (score 0):

First of all when i openened the webpage, it looked completely different as shown on the picture. However, i suggest to not use an element as a 'wrapper'. Just simply use a div as a wrapper with a class.

 
When you give the css to the wrapper :

```
.wrapper
{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

This way the width and height of your wrapper(also the content in it) will adjust based on the width of the available space.

Next thing, you should notice that you also could markup the anchor elements. Now your elements has no with or height, it just function for clicking. The anchors could just have the same markup as a div.

Also i would give the box height a static height, so you get a better 'block' effect.

This is just a little aspect of the whole webpage, but i would work like this.

 Hope you can do something with this :)

Answer (score 0):

It would be best to establish a grid system of some kind, even a rough one to lay out items such as these.

I've mocked up a quick example here: [**Codepen Example**](http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/oyfur)